# PHP 5.4.28 giving bad header for bad header for simple phpinfo script

Tags: php, apache, centos6

There was a memcache installation that went bad.
And now the **index.php** which only has below code gives malformed header !

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Error:
***malformed header from script. Bad header=phpinfo(): index.php***

The reason I think it's 5.4.28 version is because that's what php -v shows.
I've read on other forums that, it might not be the actual php version.

I'm worried if my php installation is corrupted, hence wanted to run the above to just see if it worked.

Any pointers on what might be wrong ?

**More info**

- PHP module : To see which php modules are loaded, I ran *httpd -M*, out of the 60 modules loaded, this one had php in it: **suphp_module (shared)**
- OS is ***CentOS 6.9***

Answer (score -1):

One solution I found on the internet is this:

http://www.mariusc.name/fix-error-malformed-header-script-bad-header-php-54-56.html

Look for magic_quotes_cpg, register_globals and all that deprecated crap of PHP and turn it off - if your code allows that.

Comment: dang.. so I should probably revert back to the older php version.. I see I have 5.3.3 & 5.4.28 installed. How do I tell apache to use the older version ?

Comment: How about upgrading to a newer version. PHP 5.4 is already out of support. Go for PHP 5.6 at least. It is much faster as well.

Comment: Using an older version of Laravel Framework 4.x. It stopped working with 5.4 & pretty sure it won't work with 5.6 either. Currently have to complete the project on this one. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Tell Apache which PHP version to use is very simple to google, my friend: https://serverfault.com/questions/428800/how-do-i-tell-apache-which-php-to-use

Comment: That's the crazy thing, I'm not able to find which php version is being used, since the module loaded is "suphp_module (shared)"